# Doctrine 2 Criteria using multiple orderings

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to order a selection created by `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria`, 
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections
with multiple order attributes as specified possible (?) in the specification of criteria

```
/**
 * @param array $orderings
 * @return Criteria
 */
public function orderBy(array $orderings);
```

, however, the collection sorted only takes notice of my first entry in the sorting array. My array of $orderings looks like

```
array(5) { ["col1"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["col2"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["col3"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["col4"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["col5"]=> string(3) "ASC" }
```

Any ideas? The docs mentions andX() in the bottom of the page linked earlier but I can't figure out how I would use it in this case.

Cheers, 
P

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug. Hopefully some genius will fix it soon :)

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5540#issuecomment-163442353